# UITableViewCell repeating UIImages

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This again is more of a math problem than anything else. I have 10 pictures in my resource bundle

```
sample_pic1.jpg
sample_pic2.jpg
sample_pic3.jpg
...
sample_pic10.jpg
```

I have a table view with 100 rows. What I want to do is show the 10 sample pictures every 10 rows in cell image. Basically they keep repeating every 10 rows. The problem I have is I cannot think of a logic to repeat the images?

This is what I have.

NOTE: here indexPath.row keeps going from 0 through 99. So that is something I can use

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath ... indexPath.row: %d", indexPath.row);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }//nil-check


        int imageCounter = (indexPath.row+1);

        //ofcourse this logic doesn't work for rows 21 and up!
        if (imageCounter > 10)
        {
            imageCounter = (indexPath.row+1) - 10;
        }



        NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d ... imageCounter: %d ...", indexPath.row, imageCounter);

        NSMutableString *tmpImgStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"sample_pic%d.jpg", imageCounter];

        UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:tmpImgStr];
        cell.imageView.image = myimage;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use modulo operator to repeat image number each 10 rows, and add 1 to take into account that your images are numbered starting 1:

```
int imageCounter = (indexPath.row % 10) + 1;
NSMutableString *tmpImgStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"sample_pic%d.jpg", imageCounter];
```

Comment: 1/2 way typing the same thing. Clean, simple, awesome.

Comment: my god man. This possibly can't be that simple! Thank you, it works.